# how do I open pages by id?

Tags: reactjs

I have the ShowCardDescription component by clicking on which the Description component is opened. I need the page address to change when the Description component is opened. I tried to do that, but I don't think it's right. I read the documentation for the react-router-dom and tried to do it by analogy. But I don't think it's right.

Help me, please

```js
class MainContent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isToggleOn: true
        };
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick() {
        this.setState({
            isToggleOn: !this.state.isToggleOn
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <div id='wrapp'>
                        <BrowserRouter>
                            <Link to='events/1'>
                                <ShowCardDescription isToggleOn={this.state.isToggleOn} handleClick={this.handleClick}>
                                </ShowCardDescription>
                            </Link>
                            <Switch>
                                <Route path='/events/:id'>
                                    <Description/>
                                </Route>
                            </Switch>
                        </BrowserRouter>
                     </div>
        ) 

ReactDOM.render(
    <MainContent />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: what does the `ShowCardDescription` do ? can you post the code of that component too ?

Comment: They're just showing the dive element. Do you need a code or do you understand?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. If you're asking how to get the URL to change when you click the link, that appears to be working: https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-water-rjm5t?file=/src/App.js

Comment: can you please show an example when clicking on each of the links shows a different url? when there are a lot of references